# How to disable a button using UI local time format from 10.pm to 9.am and show an alert dialog

Tags: java, android

I have a fast food app the one has to be disabled from 10.pm to 9.am, what I really need is to disable a button using UI local time format during that time and show an alert dialog base on the same principle I been searching for and nothing... please help and thanks.

Comment: Why not just get currentTime and check for hours, if it is between 10 PM and 9 AM disable, else enable?

Comment: An example code (snippet) well appreciated... I'm a beginner on android apps with no previous knowledge. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get hour of the day using this:

```
int hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

[HOUR_OF_DAY](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#HOUR_OF_DAY) will give you 24-hour time. Then just check something like this:

```
if (hour >= 22 && hour <= 9) button.setEnabled(false);
```

Now there are few options to disable the button. You can use:

- `setClickable(false)`
- `setEnabled(false)`
- `setOnClickListener(null)`

Notice that if you `setOnClickListener(null)` then you need to set your listener again if the time is correct.

Comment: Well after a few hours playing around finally got this...


`Button sendMenuOrder = findViewById(R.id.goMenuOrder);
int hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
if (hour >= 8 && hour <= 19) sendMenuOrder.setEnabled(true);
else sendMenuOrder.setEnabled(false);`


it works great, thank you so much I really appreciate your time and support, best regards, and stay healthy.

Note: if I want to disable at 8.pm has to be set to 7.pm (19 on 24-hour mode).

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy coding!